# Fast elimination of duplicate lines across multiple files

Tags: bash, files, awk, performance

I have a huge amount of data in which each (data-)line should be unique.

There are a lot of files in one folder in which this is already true. It is about 15GB splitted into roughly 170 files with 1000000 lines. Let's call that folder `foo`.

Now there is a second folder (`bar`) with even more data: In each file, there are no multiple entries. The intersection of two files in `bar` is not necessarily empty. There are roughly 15k lines in each of the files there (and there are several thousands of files in `bar`).

Right now I'm using

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=$0;next}!a[$0]' foo/file bar/file > tmp
mv tmp bar/file
```

and a loop over all files in `foo` and a loop over all files in `bar`. I break the loop over `foo` if the `bar/file` is empty. I have parallelized this by locking (for use on several nodes) and parallel execution (on each node). But still, this needs a heck of a long time.

What are possibilities of improving performance? What is the ideal file size of files in `foo`? Of course this is machine dependent (RAM/CPU/storage), but what is a good rule of thumbs here?

**tl;dr**: `foo` contains unique data lines, `bar` contains data lines which can appear multiple times in `bar`and `foo`. Eliminate duplicates in `bar` such that they can be merged with `foo`

**[Update]** There are no empty lines **[/Update]**

Comment: Have you considered sorting your file contents, and then running `uniq`? I've no idea if that would be faster or not, but an idea nonetheless.

Comment: @ire_and_curses: Indeed, this is a new idea. But how to approach that with multiple files? Joining them seems to be a bad idea. I don't see a "multiple file" option in uniq (but I only had a quick lock at the man page)

Comment: When you deal with large files, you must not use AWK arrays. Running 'cat foo/file bar/file | sort | uniq' looks like a good solution (if that is what you want to achive). Why do you think its a bad idea?

Comment: @EranBen-Natan You're right. I somehow didn't think of piping. I will try this shortly. Thanks!

Comment: @EranBen-Natan : There is no need (and its a performance drain) to do `cat foo bar|sort|uniq` when you can do `sort -u foo bar` .

Comment: The `sort -u` approach is about 2.5 times slower than the current awk solution (at least on my machine). `comm -13` seems to give a slight advantage though

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but would you be better off loading them into a database and using an SQL query to process this?

Comment: @Rqomey I have no experience with databases, but maybe it's a good idea. It's still a huge amount of data: 15GB in foo and 75GB in bar.

Comment: Yes, perhaps we could ask that question on dba.se

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but your code can be optimised to:

```
awk '!x{a[$0];next}; !($0 in a)' foo/file x=1 bar/file > tmp
```

(yours had issues for empty lines or lines resolving to "0" in them I think)

If the files are sorted, you could do:

```
comm -13 foo/file bar/file > tmp
```

If they're not (ksh93. zsh or bash syntax):

```
comm -13  <(sort foo/file) <(sort bar/file) > tmp
```

(not necessarily faster than the awk solution)

Also, especially with GNU awk, you may get better performance by setting the locale to C/POSIX:

```
LC_ALL=C awk ...
```

Comment: I'm using your `comm -13` approach now and there is a noticeable speed up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i had multiple files each of few MB in size  and i have tried this which works for me:

```
sort *.csv | uniq -d
```

This will give you duplicate records from your file and then you can redirect output to a single file to get duplicate record and removing `-d` will give you all unique record.

Comment: So what is your answer to *this* question?  `sort * | uniq`?  That was suggested n a comment over 2½ years ago.